# Can I drop recovery partitions on my Windows 10 after having make a recovery drive?

Tags: backup, partitioning, windows-10, data-recovery

I want to install Ubuntu (with a dual-boot) on my new laptop but I have already 5 partitions on my SSD: 1 EFI partition, 1 for the Windows OS and 3 as recovery partitions.

I created a recovery drive (on a USB drive) as recommended and I want to know if I can drop some partitions to make space for my Ubuntu without any risks if I want to totally recover my Windows. Can I, at least, drop the 3 recovery partitions?

What are the recommendations?

Comment: Why are you worried about having 5 partitions, just create, a 6th partition

Comment: I want to save space on my disk. Also, I usually use 4 partitions when I make a dual-boot Windows/Linux : Windows partition, Linux partition, documents partition and swap. Because there is a limit of 4 physical partitions on a disk, I don't really know if it is possible to use logical partition in my case.

Comment: GPT partitions don't have a 4 partition limit. There is absolutely no reason to consolidate your partitions and you will cause more work and likely break your Windows installation if you attempt to consolidate your partitions

Comment: Ok! Thanks to your comment, I just learned that MBR disks are not use anymore ... So, I just have to divide my Windows partition with the utility provide by Windows, right?

Comment: Your not using MBR, they can still be used, Windows 10 fully supports MBR.  Your disk is currently GPT, per your own statements, thus there is no limitation to the number of partitions that can exist.

Comment: But yes, once you've created a physical recovery disk, in most cases you should no longer need a recovery partition.

Comment: In most cases ?